URL reload leading to 404
I'm developing a PWA and i'm experiencing a strange issue: my components load perfectly but if i try to reload it, i end up getting an error message. I need to first go back to a URL without component. Example:

https://emptylegs.corp-jet.world/ takes me to the signin page;
after login, i see this URL: https://emptylegs.corp-jet.world/home;
i i try to reload https://emptylegs.corp-jet.world/home, i end up with this message:

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@emptylegs.corp-jet.world to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

so i must restart with https://emptylegs.corp-jet.world/ to resume browsing.

I tries to fix the routes component but it didn't help:
import { Routes, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './components/notfound/notfound.component';
import { MapComponent } from './components/map/map.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './components/signin/signin.component';
import { UserprofileComponent } from './components/userprofile/userprofile.component';
import { UserSubscribeComponent } from './components/user-subscribe/user-subscribe.component';
import { BrokerprofileComponent } from './components/brokerprofile/brokerprofile.component';
import { OperatorprofileComponent } from './components/operatorprofile/operatorprofile.component';
import { FlightProfileComponent } from './components/flight-profile/flight-profile.component';
import { brokerAuthGuard } from './guards/broker-auth.guard';
import { operatorAuthGuard } from './guards/operatorauth.guard';
import { subscriptionPageGuard } from './guards/subscriptionpage.guard';
import { SecretComponent } from './components/secret/secret.component';
import { homeGuard } from './guards/homeguard.guard';
import { AdminConsoleComponent } from './components/admin-console/admin-console.component';


export const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/signin',
        pathMatch: 'full',

    },
    {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SigninComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: MapComponent,
        canActivate: [homeGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'flightprofile',
        component: FlightProfileComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: UserprofileComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'broker',
                component: BrokerprofileComponent,
                canActivate: [brokerAuthGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'operator',
                component: OperatorprofileComponent,
                canActivate: [operatorAuthGuard]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'subscribe',
        component: UserSubscribeComponent,
        canActivate: [subscriptionPageGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'secret',
        component: SecretComponent,

    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminConsoleComponent,

    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: NotfoundComponent,
    },
];



this should be configured on the server. what server are you using to serve your application?

sounds like a looping redirect.  Check any server-side code that performs redirection.  (when not using hash location strategy sometimes people will setup a redirect to avoid 404 when using browser refresh at a certain route)

@Andrei: Apache Version 2.4.59 (i think, i'm purely a front-end dev)

@browsermator: where do i find server-side code?

Just write it up or discuss with whoever setup the server.  The server-side code is on the server.
